# Parametro en directiva *ngFor Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-directivas

## Buen dia.

Tengo un componente que tiene 3 parametros de entrada

1-json_columnas

2-json_filas

3-nombre_filtro

como puedo hacer para que el nombre_filtro quede indicado como el pipe a filtrar en ese grupo de datos.

#### component.ts

```
@Input('json_columnas') columnas:[{}];
@Input('json_filas') filas:[{}];

//Pipe para buscar
@Input('nombre_filtro') pipeFiltro:string;
```

#### component.html

...

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of filas | pipeFiltro: itemABuscar; let i=index" >
{{item.nombre}}
</tr>
```

Comment: A ver si entendi, quieres acceder al valor del pipe? Osea a `itemABuscar`?

Comment: mm no, lo que yo quiero es poder indicarle al ngFor que pipe usar,es decir que el componente padre le pueda enviar al componente hijo un valor para que filtre estos datos con este pipe

Comment: Osea, quieres pasar el pipe dinamicamente en vez de tener que especificarlo en el `*ngFor`?

Comment: Si exactamente quiero que el pipe sea dinamico

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos pienso que es mejor un `Pipe` general, que tenga un segundo parámetro: "tipo" por ejemplo, y en la lógica definida en el `Pipe`
se evalúe dicho tipo para decidir qué acción realizar. Acción que recomiendo esté en un servicio o, en cualquier caso, definida de forma modular.

Component

```
@Input('nombre_filtro') tipoFiltro:string;
```

Template

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of filas | filtro:itemABuscar:tipoFiltro; let i=index" >
    {{item.nombre}}
</tr>
```

Pipe

```
transform(item: any, itemABuscar: any, tipoFiltro: string): any {

    switch (tipoFiltro) {
        case 'filtroA':
            // ...
            break;

        case 'filtroB':
            // ...
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```